# Angular remove parent element without affecting children

Tags: angular

In Angular, is there anyway to remove a parent element without removing it's child elements. I know there are a few ways to do this with jQuery, but I'd rather not use jQuery.

Here are the specifics: I have a list that I want to toggle between being a dropdown or breadcrumbs based on screen size. The li elements are essentially the same it's just their parent uls that need to be swapped out. Currently I am able to switch between the two, but I am looking for a way to not repeat my li elements to reduce the repetitiveness of my code.

Dropdown parent:

```
<ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
```

Breadcrumb parent:

`<ul class="custom-breadcrumb nav nav-fill"`

Normally I would just use something like [className]=... to conditionally swap out the classes. But because of the `*dropdownMenu` that I'm using with ngx-bootstrap to make the dropdown work I need to swap out the who ul element.

So far anything that I've tried removes both the parent ul and child li elements.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You say you have tried something, can you show that in the post?

Comment: You can achieve this using *ngIf right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an `ngIf ... else` directive to select which parent element is displayed in the view. To avoid repeating the markup for the list items, put them in an `ng-template` and insert that template in the parent with an `ngTemplateOutlet` directive.

```
<ul *ngIf="condition else dropdown" class="custom-breadcrumb nav nav-fill">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listItems"></ng-container>
</ul>
<ng-template #dropdown>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listItems"></ng-container>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #listItems>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ng-template>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ygqca) for a demo.

Comment: Your code example will fail, because you cannot apply more than one structural directive to one element. You need to wrap the `*dropdownMenu` element with `<ng-template [ngIf]="...">`.

Comment: @cyrix - Thanks for the heads up. I swapped the `ul` elements to avoid the problem. By the way, if I had chosen to wrap the first `ul` element, it would have  had to be with `ng-container` (rather than `ng-template`). See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bfxsb).

Comment: yeah swapping the `ul` elements also works :) Btw there's no need for a `ng-container` element when using `ngIf`-directive (also applies for the `ngTemplateOutlet`). See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtmfhq)

Comment: @ConnorsFan that worked perfectly! Thank you for this, it's such a useful trick